# How can i add a 2dView having text in ARkit scene iOS

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

How can i add a 2dView having text in ARkit scene iOS.How can i add that view in top of a node that won't rotate when we rotate the node.[image]

Answer (score 21):

You can add a `SCNPlane` and use a [`SCNLookAtConstraint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnlookatconstraint) to so that the plane always looks at the camera.

You can create a custom material and set it's [material properties](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnlookatconstraint) to:

> - A color (UIColor or CGColor), specifying a constant color across the material’s surface
>     A number (
> - An image (UIImage or CGImage), specifying a texture to be mapped across the material’s surface
> - A Core Animation layer (CALayer)
> - A texture (SKTexture, MDLTexture, MTLTexture, or GLKTextureInfo)
> - A SpriteKit scene (SKScene)

You can also display animated contents using CoreAnimation or SpriteKit but

> SceneKit cannot use a layer that is already being displayed elsewhere (for example, the backing layer of a UIView object)

---

Here is an example using SpriteKit:

1. Create your SpriteKit Scene:

e.g.:

```
let skScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))
skScene.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

let rectangle = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200), cornerRadius: 10)
rectangle.fillColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.807843148708344, green: 0.0274509806185961, blue: 0.333333343267441, alpha: 1.0)
rectangle.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.439215689897537, green: 0.0117647061124444, blue: 0.192156866192818, alpha: 1.0)
rectangle.lineWidth = 5
rectangle.alpha = 0.4
let labelNode = SKLabelNode(text: "Hello World")
labelNode.fontSize = 20
labelNode.fontName = "San Fransisco"
labelNode.position = CGPoint(x:100,y:100)
skScene.addChild(rectangle)
skScene.addChild(labelNode)
```

2. Create your plane and set the scene as your material property

e.g.

```
let plane = SCNPlane(width: 20, height: 20)
let material = SCNMaterial()
material.isDoubleSided = true
material.diffuse.contents = skScene
plane.materials = [material]
let node = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

3. Animate your scene

e.g.

```
labelNode.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: .pi, duration: 2)))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for reply when i add this code in ARKit example 
it terminate when i try to add Plane node in my scene
self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)

It give this error
 "validateDepthStencilState:3675: failed assertion `MTLDepthStencilDescriptor uses frontFaceStencil but MTLRenderPassDescriptor has a nil stencilAttachment texture'"

Any idea? please help

Comment: I only have testes the code in a SceneKit playground. I have no idea why it should not work in ARKit

Comment: thanks for the help its because of this line skScene.addChild(rectangle)
need to remove that line to run it

Comment: @orangenkopf you mention something about using an SCNLookAtConstraint but don't have that in your example, could you expound on that. also what if I want to present a scene `.presentScene(skScene)`

Comment: Thanks for this! I've implemented this into my AR testcase without the animation. When I run this, the text of SKLabelNode is mirrored. Do you have any clue why? here you can get an impression of what I'd tried to describe; https://imgur.com/a/RwZn4

Comment: @aofs No, but you can mirror the material using the [`SCNMaterialProperty.contentsTransform`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/1395388-contentstransform) property.

Comment: @aofs hey, I'm solving similar problem as you were, I'm able to display plane on screen, but didn't have any luck to display a SKScene as material to this plane, can you provide any help/sample code how did you solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Mysiaq I've switched back to the "View as image" method.. See here: https://gist.github.com/katunch/d251ad400911c6381b37c855da36cff7

Comment: If you stop rotating action, your text will be shown in *upside down* . To resolve it, you need to add  `material.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4Translate(SCNMatrix4MakeScale(1, -1, 1), 0, 1, 0)` in step number 2.

Comment: @aofs The issue with mirrored text from SKLabelNode sounds like the rotation of your plane.  For example, if you're rotating by (-.pi/2), try changing it to (.pi/2)

Answer (score 0):

Probably worth mentioning that you can also use a couple of other things for contents... A list can be found here...
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/1395372-contents

I tried the code from the answer above and it worked fine, but was slowing down my FPS because I have many nodes that need it. And the SKScene is probable quite heavy.

I was able to use an SKView with a SKLabelNode but the problem was that the text would not update visually, My guess would be that I would have to call texture(from:) every time and I figured that would be just as slow
SKView texture(from:)
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skview/1520114-texture

I saw another way to do it with a CALayer but thought id have the same problem with changing text so I just went with SCNText.

Also worth mentioning SCNBillboardConstraint as an alternative to LookatConstraint
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnbillboardconstraint