# Adding SKShapeNode.fillColor results in stencil error

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, scenekit

I am trying to place several `SKScene` inside a `SCNScene`.

In the `SKScene`, I draw a rectangle using `SKShapeNode`, and I set its fill color to red.

The code passed compilation. However, the rectangle comes into screen, a run time error resulted:

```
failed assertion `MTLDepthStencilDescriptor uses frontFaceStencil but MTLRenderPassDescriptor has a nil stencilAttachment texture'
```

What could be the cause of this error? I am using iOS 11 (beta 8.0) and xcode 9 (Beta)

Comment: This is an error I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45317366/how-can-i-add-a-2dview-having-text-in-arkit-scene-ios/45325051#45325051) before so I think it does not happen in iOS 10. It is probably a bug, fill a report with apple!

Comment: @orangenkopf You are correct. I actually follows the tutorial in that thread.

Comment: This error should not occur when you are not debugging with xcode. Try to run the app on the device without xcode

Comment: Thanks man. I tried device only and it works for me. This should be my work around for now. I filed Apple bug 34241470 for this issue.