# Mapping 3D SceneKit Node-Position to 2D Coordinate - projectPoint doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit

I am displaying a 3d model consisting of several SNNodes in SceneKit.

I am displaying a 2D SpriteKit node on the sceneview-overlay view. The 2D-node position should always be in front of a particular 3D SCNNode.

How can I map the 3D position to the SpriteKit 2D position?

I tried `let screenPoint = sceneView.projectPoint(my3dNode)`, but this doesn't work: even when the my3dNode is in the center of the screen, the function returns very weird values (e.g. negative values or over 1000).

Do you have any ideas why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be that it's projecting from the untranslated, unmodified node position, or that the node is a child of another node, thus changing its frame of reference. Try using `myNode.presentation.worldPosition` as the input for `projectPoint`.

[EDIT]

Reading a bit closer, would you not be better off creating a flat texture of your sprite, attach it to the node in question, give it a 'billboard' constraint and set its Z order so that it always appears in front?

Comment: @Ash is it same for converting 3d world coordinated point to 2d pixel coordinate system. In this case also i am getting same kind of results

Comment: That seems to be exactly what the OP was attempting to do, so if I'm understanding you correctly, then yes. The input for the `projectPoint` function must be in the world's frame of reference. In my example I am using a node's position, but any 3D vector representing a point in space should do. Essentially, it's just putting that value through the renderer's transformation matrix.

If you need to go from 2D to 3D coordinates, use `unprojectPoint` instead.

Comment: Hi @Ash! Would you be able to help me with a similar ARkit/Scenekit related question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783206/projecting-the-arkit-face-tracking-3d-mesh-to-2d-image-coordinates